# My HP Pavilion g series does not shutdown

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, hp

Hi my laptop is HP Pavilion g series and the OS on it is Ubuntu 14.04.The problem is when I hit shutdown it freezes at the greeter page where it shows the Ubuntu word and the dots beneath it. I tried `sudo poweroff` , `sudo shutdown -P now`, `sudo init 0`, and even i tried adjusting the grub with these commands:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and removing this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" acpi=force apm=power_off
```

(I found this solution on the internet but it also didn't work). So please If you happen to know any real solution for turning the laptop off, write it here, and I will be highly appreciated.

Comment: change the words `quiet splash` to `profile` , run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. Then, try to poweroff the computer and you will see a verbose output and hopefully will see where or what the system is getting hung up on when you try to shut down. Please post this info if relevant to help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @mschid I changed it, and now here what it looks like when it freezes.     The last three lines are:    *Deactivating swap...    *Will now halt                      [      90.446855]  reboot:  Power down

Comment: do you have these packages installed? `sudo apt-get install acpi-support acpid acpi acpitool libacpi0`

Comment: @mchid no i don't have them, Do i need to do that

Comment: You may need them.  acpi-support provides scripts for handling acpi events such as detecting loss and gain of AC power, lid closure, certain buttons (Asus, IBM, Lenovo, Panasonic, Sony, Toshiba), suspend, hibernate, resume and sometimes screenbrightness as well.  Modern computers support ACPI "to allow intelligent power management on your system ". When an event occurs, ACPI  executes programs to handle the events (such as powering off) according to the acpid description. The acpi package is for displaying acpi info; acpi-tool provides command line function and libacpi0 is support lib.

Comment: Also, I believe the correct syntax for /etc/default/grub would be one of the following `"quiet-splah acpi=power-off"` or `"quiet-splash acpi=off apm=on apm=power-off"` or `"quiet-splash acpi=off apm=on acpi=power-off"` **notice they are within the quotation marks**

Answer (score 0):

You may need ACPI support for your laptop. Run the following commands to install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acpi-support acpid acpi acpitool libacpi0
```

A reboot may also be necessary.

As you can see [in this loosly related example](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/linux-acpi-and-bios-acpi-problem-to-understand-and-giving-out-bugs-469366/), typically, when ACPI is disabled, the computer will halt but will not shut down when ACPI support is needed.

Comment: I installed these packages I rebooted and tried to turn my PC off, but also it didn't work. The PC froze at the same point.

Comment: @IsmaelAlSabe' read my comment above about your /etc/default/grub file and don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after making any changes.

Comment: I reached the second solution when everything went wrong. I did the second configuration to the grub  "quiet-splash acpi=off apm=on apm=power-off" after updating the grub and rebooting, I couldn't connect to the WIFI. Also, when I write in the terminal for example if i press the y button it writes yyyyyyyyyyy. I actually do not know what happened, and because I couldn't do anything I re-installed Ubuntu once again, and now I am afraid to do the third one. maybe it's a bug?